# Vue-Dropzone setOption method not working

Tags: vue.js, dropzone, vue-dropzone

Im trying to set the url dynamically on a dropzone elements options.
According to the documentation, you use the setOption method to change options after initialization.

So Im doing this...

```
var url ='http://myurl'
this.$refs.dropzone1.setOption('url', url)
```

But Im getting this error...

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
 at VueComponent.setOption (vue2Dropzone.js?2af3:1)
```

So then I tried doing this....

```
 var url ='http://myurl'
 this.$refs.dropzone1.dropzone.setOption('url', url)
```

and I got this...

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setOption' of undefined
 at VueComponent.setOption (vue2Dropzone.js?2af3:1)
```

Then I tried just setting the option directly, without the method, and that worked cuz it changes it.  But it doesnt actually 'change' because its obviously inititialized already.

```
this.$refs.dropzone1.dropzone.options.url = url
```

How do I use setOption properly?? because apparently, using it the way the documentation states, doesnt work?

Maybe I have a broken version?? Im using v3.2.2

Answer (score 0):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
at VueComponent.setOption (vue2Dropzone.js?2af3:1)
```

This means you probably called `setOption()` before `<vue-dropzone>` was mounted.

(Because `this.dropzone.options` should be available after [mounted()](https://github.com/rowanwins/vue-dropzone/blob/v3.2.2/src/components/vue-dropzone.vue#L203) is called)

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setOption' of undefined
```

Calling `setOption()` on the dropzone property inside the component wouldn't work either because it also wouldn't be initialised yet and secondly because [Dropzone.js](https://gitlab.com/meno/dropzone/blob/master/src/dropzone.js) doesn't have such a method.

Setting it directly also shouldn't work, or are you setting that at different time?

Comment: Im calling setOption long after vue-dropzone is mounted.  The setOption is fired when I click a button.  So the component is definitely mounted.  As its visible.

Comment: What a strange bug. Try `console.log(this.$refs.dropzone1)` and try finding out when the `<vue-dropzone>` component doesn't have a dropzone property with a options property anymore.